xunit incredibly slower after upgrading from 2.7.1
I am trying to upgrade xunit on https://github.com/MarkCiliaVincenti/AsyncKeyedLock/, currently on 2.7.1
The issue I have is that any version of xunit after 2.7.1 runs the tests considerably slower, both when I test locally on my dev machine as well as on Github Actions (here they usually take 2.5 to 3 mins to run with 2.7.1 but over 25 minutes to run on 2.8.0+).
I'm a bit at a loss at what I should do at this point.

According to the release notes of xunit 2.8.0, the default parallelization algorithm was changed.
Fixed by setting a config setting of parallelAlgorithm as explained at https://xunit.net/docs/configuration-files#parallelAlgorithm
